# Query Statistics for my app responds with "No Requests"

Tags: bug, stackapps, statistics

When I access [Query Statistics](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/view/2859/query-stats) for [my app](https://stackapps.com/questions/885/stackathlon-2-5-leader-board-for-users-active-on-multiple-sites) (while logged in) I get "No Requests"

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

I'm using Chrome 34 on Ubuntu.

Comment: No, it's just been completely broken for a while. :(

Comment: That question may be a duplicate, but it's a poor search target and it doesn't have an answer while this one has an answer in the form of a comment.

Comment: It's not really an answer to the actual issue though, just stating that it's indeed a bug.

Comment: True. "Response" would have been a better word. The other question has a confirmation rather than an answer or response.